# Adding two Optionals in a Predicate

Tags: java, option-type

I have to write a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) in Java where I can query the input to predicate to get two `Optional<Integer>` objects. I have to return true or false based on the combined value of the two Optionals. Is there some better way to do it other than checking the `isPresent()` and then `get()` those values and add.

```java
// Here assuming the comparingValue and integer1 and integer2 are all initialised with values.
// The isGreaterOrEqual function has an implementation.

int comparingValue;
Optional<Integer> integer1;
Optional<Integer> integer2;
if (integer1.isPresent() && integer2.isPresent()) 
    return isGreaterOrEqual(comparingValue, integer1.get() + integer2.get());
if (integer1.isPresent())
    return isGreaterOrEqual(comparingValue, integer1.get());
else if (integer2.isPresent()) 
    return isGreaterOrEqual(comparingValue, integer2.get());
else
    return false;
```

Comment: 1. your code doesn't compile, as Optional instances and `comparingValue` are not initialized; 2. It's not clear what exactly you're using as `compare`. Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @ManasGupta I'd rename this compare function, as the described behavior is unusual for a function with this name - perhaps call it `isGreaterOrEqual`?

Comment: I agree with Hulk here. `compare` is [a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) of the widely-known Comparator interface, which in turn returns an integer rather than a `boolean`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```java
return Stream.of(integer1, integer2)
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .reduce((a, b) -> a + b)
    .map(t -> isGreaterOrEqual(comparingValue, t))
    .orElse(false);
```

<strike>It is not without using `isPresent` and `get`, but it is fluent-style.</strike> → Thanks to Hulk's comment, it actually *is* without `isPresent` and `get`.

What happens here in the abovementioned code, is we build a stream of the two `Optional<Integer>`s, and then:

- if both optionals are nonempty, add their values and compare to `comparingValue`
- if exactly one of the optionals is nonempty, compare to `comparingValue`
- if both are empty, return `false`.

The advantage of this approach is that it allows to add more optionals if desired:

```java
public boolean test(int comparingValue, Optional<Integer> optionalIntegers...) {
    Stream.of(optionalIntegers)
```

---

Regarding your comments about 'generalization' — of course, you cannot use the `+` operator with objects other than `String` and the wrapper classes of numeric types. If we assume your class has a `merge` method with the following signature:

```java
Money add(Money m1)
```

then you only need to replace the line with `reduce` to the following:

```java
.reduce((a, b) -> a.add(b))
```

or just

```java
.reduce(Money::add)
```

---

#### Java 8

For Java 8, you could replace `.flatMap(Optional::stream)` by

```java
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: Since Optional.stream is added in JDK9 can you suggest an alternate solution for JDK8 or below?

Comment: For JDK 8 or less, can this be done - 
```Optional<Money> total = Stream.of(integer1, integer2).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).reduce(Money::add); return total.map(amount -> isGreaterOrEqual(amount, comparisonValue).orElse(false);```

Comment: @heisenberg I have updated the answer to include Java 8 code.

Answer (score 7):

You can shorten it to:

```
if (integer1.isPresent() || integer2.isPresent()) {
    return compare(comparingValue, integer1.orElse(0) + integer2.orElse(0));
} else {
    return false;
}
```

---

**Update**, regarding your comment about generalization.
If you want to cover the most general case and *don't* have any "default values" (like `0`) which can be "combined" with the other value before comparing (like `x + 0`), then the IF-cascade you have is the best you can get. You can rewrite it with `Optional`'s methods and convert it to a single expression, but in essence it' still the same IF-cascade with 4 cases:

```
return 
  optValue1.map(
    // value1 is present
    value1 -> optValue2.map(
      // value2 is also present ==> combine and compare
      value2 -> compare(comparingValue, combine(value1, value2))
    ).orElseGet(
      // value2 is not present ==> use value1
      () -> compare(comparingValue, value1)
    )
  ).orElseGet(
    // value1 is not present
    optValue2.map(
      // value2 is present ==> use value2
      value2 -> compare(comparingValue, value2)
    ).orElse(
      // value2 is also not present ==> return default result
      false
    )
  );
```

The "classic" IF-cascade seems even more readable to me :)

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I think `||` is correct.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri, I didn't want to change the OP's original behavior. Without the `if`, the result would be `true` if both values are absent and `comparingValue` is zero.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Because if both `Optional`s are empty, `false` must be returned.

Comment: An extension: What if it's not integers but another object such that we don't have the functionality of doing ```x.orElse(0)``` but it provides a method to compare and add the objects.
Assuming the object can be -
```class IntegerExtension {int amount;  String region;}```

Comment: @ManasGupta then it could change to `map(accessor).orElse(0)`, but it would be better to ask that as a new question.

Comment: @Hulk Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @ManasGupta I'm talking about using [Optional.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) to access the field. But the comment section for an answer is not the right place for this discussion. Please post a separate question if this is still unclear.